# Parse IOS push dropping messages when sent consecutively

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification

Parse is dropping pushes for IOS. I send 10 messages in a row, with 3 secs interval, works well for Android, but parse drops messages randomly for IOS. The messages are sent through a clound function, which works well for Android. You can see in the picture four failed in a row then 3 succeeded in a row, then fail and succeed. my Cloud function is pretty simple, it first searches the installations and then check if it's iOS, does a little formatting and send it.

```js
Function pushToInstallations(results, messageObject, response) {
    var pushedCount = 0;
    var failedCount = 0;
    for (i in results) {
        Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
        var installation = new Parse.Installation(results[i]);
        console.log("processing installation " + i);
        // console.log(installation);
        var deviceType = installation.get("deviceType");
        console.log("installation deviceType " + deviceType);
        var payload;
        if (deviceType == "android") {
            payload = createAndroidPayload(messageObject, installation);
        } else {
            payload = createIosPayload(messageObject, installation);
        }
        var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
        console.log("installation id" + installation.get("installationId"))
        query.equalTo("installationId",     installation.get("installationId"));
        Parse.Push.send({
            where: query,
            data: payload
        }).then(function() {
            pushedCount++;
            .....
        }, function(error) {
            failedCount++;
            .....
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to know that the **Push Notification** is not 100% guarantee. And it's indicated by Apple clearly.

Comment: This issue should be with Parse. The figure *should* indicate that the messages are NOT sent to apple. We have been using UrbanAirship on which we've never seen situations this bad.

Comment: Same cloud code, same test script, no dropping message today. I can only say Parse(or Parse+Apple) is a magic:D. Will have to continue monitoring though...